# openweathermap weather data by zip code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, weather, openweathermap

i need to make it so that when a zip code is typed into the box and the submit button is clicked, the name of the city shows up under it. when i click the button after putting a zip code the city name doesn't show up. it says the error is that wallOfText is not a function but i'm not sure how to fix it. any help would be appreciated!! here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
Enter your zip code:<br><input type="text" id="zipBox" name="zipCode"><br><br>
<button onclick="weatherFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
    function weatherFunction() {
        var zip = document.getElementById("zipBox").value;
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" +zip+ ",us&appid=b3456f9acbfa64fc4495e6696ecdc9a5",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (wallOfText) {
                    city = wallOfText("name");
                    if (zip != null) {
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = wallOfText;

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're attempting to call `wallOfText` like it's a function, when in fact it's the object which has been deserialised from the response of the AJAX call. As such, you need to access the object's `name` property to set the `city` variable, then use that to set the `text()` of the `#result` element.

Note that the document.ready handler within the function is redundant, and you should be doing the `zip` value validation *before* you make the request. I also updated the logic to use jQuery to bind the event handler on the button instead of the outdated `onclick` attribute. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $('#send').click(function() {
    var zip = $("#zipBox").val();
    if (zip !== '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip + ",us&appid=b3456f9acbfa64fc4495e6696ecdc9a5",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(wallOfText) {
          var city = wallOfText.name;
          $("#result").text(city);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your zip code:<br>
<input type="text" id="zipBox" name="zipCode" value="90210" /><br /><br /> 
<button type="button" id="send">Submit</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```